# How do i return a vector of vectors class from a function?

Tags: c++

Im trying to return a vector of vectors in a function ive created, but im getting "no suitable user-defined conversion" error. vector is a vector of class objects.

```
/**function to get number of entries into an vector and pushback*/
std::vector<OrderBookEntry> AdvisorBot::EntryCount(std::string count,std::string tokens_string)
{
    //now use the tokenize func to get the string of each input
    std::vector<std::string> Tokens = CSVReader::tokenise(tokens_string, ',');

    std::string CountUserInput = count;
    int steps = std::stoi(CountUserInput);

    //pushback to entries vector of vectors
    std::vector< std::vector<OrderBookEntry> > Total_entries;

   
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            Total_entries.push_back(AdvisorBot_orderBook.getOrders(OrderBookEntry::stringToOrderBookType(Tokens[1]), Tokens[0], currentTime));
        }
        else {
            currentTime = AdvisorBot_orderBook.getNextTime(currentTime);
            Total_entries.push_back(AdvisorBot_orderBook.getOrders(OrderBookEntry::stringToOrderBookType(Tokens[1]), Tokens[0], currentTime));
        }
    }
    //return std::vector<OrderBookEntry>();
    return Total_entries;

}
```

I just want to return the vector of vectors Total Entries that i created.

Comment: If you want to return `Total_entries` which is of type `std::vector<std::vector<OrderBookEntry>>` you need to change your method return type to match it (at the moment it is `std::vector<OrderBookEntry>`).

Comment: it worked. didnt realise my function was just returning a vector, instead of vector of vectors, thank you!

Comment: Not sure, would you need a vector of vectors at all? Are there any specific semantics behind? If not, you might instead simply `insert` new values at the end of a single vector à la `std::vector<Entry> all; for(...) { auto tmp = getOrders(); all.insert(all.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end()) }`.

Comment: A [mre] leaves few places for a bug to hide. For this question, pushing the "minimal" aspect could lead to `std::vector<OrderBookEntry> EntryCount() { std::vector< std::vector<OrderBookEntry> > Total_entries; /* Do stuff */ return Total_entries; }`. Not that informative in a comment, but try writing it out with good formatting...

Comment: Side note: you are duplicating code! There's no difference in between the only line within the if-block and the second one in the else-block. You can avoid duplication by instead having `if(i != 0) { getNextTime(); } push_back(getOrders());`

Comment: Off-topic: You provide the number of iterations as `std::string` – that's not a good idea. It reduces re-usability or at least would force, if you have a numerical value available already, to first convert it to a string just to be converted back afterwards. Rather accept the `steps` as integral parameter right from the start (preferably as `size_t`). You still could provide an *overload* for convenience accepting the string, do the conversion and then call the other one.

Comment: @Aconcagua and can be even more simple if one want skip an extra if

Comment: @Aconcagua the reason for a vector of vectors is because each vector has a different timestamp that i will need to use to iterate over a CSV file

Comment: @LearningToCode The timestamps are not part of the vector, though. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to have a vector of structs then, where the structs contain both timestamp and the vector? Or do the book entries carry it? But then you still wouldn't need the vector of vectors...

Comment: @Aconcagua the vector <OrderBookEntry> contains the timestamp, thus the vector of vectors. Because i cant actually change the timestamp while im iterating, hence i just create the number of vectors i need with the different timestamp and store inside another vector. Then use a nested for loop. im sure there is a better way but idk how

Comment: @LearningToCode Well, as mentioned: Instead of two separate vectors (where you separate information far apart that actually belongs closely together) a vector of structs is better: `struct Collection { TypeOfTimestamp timestamp; std::vector<BookEntry> entries; };` and then return a `std::vector<Collection>` (change the name to whatever appears appropriate to you. Your loop then might look like: `std::vector<Collection> all; all.reserve(steps); /*avoid needless re-allocations!*/ for(size_t i = 0; i < steps; ++i) { all.emplace_back(getNextTime(), getOrders()) }` provided you wrote the

Comment: appropriate constructor for `Collection` and changed `getNextTime()` to be callable already for first timestamp, too. Or without the latter maybe: `all.emplace_back(i == 0 ? getFirstTimeStamp() : getNextTimestamp(), getOrders());`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in c++ renturnig data type is spcified. `Total_entries` is of type `std::vector<std::vector<OrderBookEntry>>`, so change return type to this.

```
std::vector<std::vector<OrderBookEntry>> AdvisorBot::EntryCount(std::string count,std::string tokens_string)
{
    //now use the tokenize func to get the string of each input
    std::vector<std::string> Tokens = CSVReader::tokenise(tokens_string, ',');

    std::string CountUserInput = count;
    int steps = std::stoi(CountUserInput);

    //pushback to entries vector of vectors
    std::vector< std::vector<OrderBookEntry> > Total_entries;

   
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            Total_entries.push_back(AdvisorBot_orderBook.getOrders(OrderBookEntry::stringToOrderBookType(Tokens[1]), Tokens[0], currentTime));
        }
        else {
            currentTime = AdvisorBot_orderBook.getNextTime(currentTime);
            Total_entries.push_back(AdvisorBot_orderBook.getOrders(OrderBookEntry::stringToOrderBookType(Tokens[1]), Tokens[0], currentTime));
        }
    }
    //return std::vector<OrderBookEntry>();
    return Total_entries;

}
```

Comment: Just as a hint: It is usually not of much value if you repeat entire code unchanged, this rather tends to make the information you actually want to provide less visible/obvious; in this concrete case it would have been sufficient just to provide the function *declaration* or alternatively you chould have shortened the body to e.g. `{ /*... */ }`.